# Рефакторинг кода на laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Отрефакторил как мог, теперь нужен паттерн, но какой в этом случае?
вопрос закрыт.

```
     public function checkCompany($company, $path)
{
    $filePathFromKias = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
    if ($company == 'komm') {
        $localDirectory = "/newpickomm/";
        $fullPath = substr(strstr($filePathFromKias, '$NEWPC'), 8);
    } elseif ($company == 'ins') {
        $localDirectory = "/filesks/";
        $fullPath = substr(strstr($filePathFromKias, 'FILESKS$'), 11);
    } elseif ($company == 'kj') {
        $localDirectory = "/pickj/";
        $fullPath = substr(strstr($filePathFromKias, 'PICKJ'), 7);
    }
    return [
        "localDir" => $localDirectory,
        "fullPath" => $fullPath
    ];
}

public function unlink($data) $data это Request 
{
    $company = $data['company'];
    $path = $data['path'];
    $checkComp =  $this->checkCompany($company, $path);
    $localDirectory = $checkComp['localDir'];
    $fullPath = $checkComp['fullPath'];
    $fileName = basename($fullPath);
    $dirName = strstr($fullPath, $fileName, true);
    $pathOfDir = $localDirectory.$dirName;
    if (!file_exists($pathOfDir)) {
        mkdir($pathOfDir, 0777, true);
    }
    unlink($pathOfDir.$fileName);
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ну для начала попробуйте без всяких паттернов, отделить повторяющуюся часть внутри IF в какую-то функцию с параметрами и вызывать её

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  сделал, теперь думаю время паттерна?)

Comment: Вряд ли, для такой задачи никакие паттерны не нужны (ну, точнее, я бы не стал). считайте что применили принцип DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю)

Comment: Паттерны для функции которая формирует ссылку и удаляет файл? А зачем создаётся директория если таковой нет, перед удалением файла? и возвращать надо, хотя бы, тот же unlink. И тут тег laravel неуместен

Comment: Теперь можно сделать так: в константы выделить типы компаний типа `const COMPANY_TYPE_KJ = 'kj';  const COMPANY_TYPE_KOMM = 'komm';` и так далее.... тоже самое сделать для магических цифр 7,8,11 и для магических строк 'PICKJ' и пр........... далее создать ассоциативный массив, в котом ключ будет COMPANY_TYPE, а в значении будет ещё один ассоциативный массив где будет ключи localDirectory, fullPath  и что там ещё..........далее просто можно будет в функции `checkCompany` возвращать данные из этого массива по ключу

Comment: зы. сейчас функция unlink нигде не применена....это я так, к слову

Comment: Если надо под Laravel рефакторить то создайте Request, в нём делайте все манипуляции (напр. в методе prepareForValidation()) чтобы получить ссылку (её же добавляете параметром в $request) и в самом контроллере уже делаете только unlink